# what is the difference b/w Cursor and Loop of SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I can't figure out why to use cursor when we have different loops to iterate over data in SQL. Can you please guide me here and what's the difference and when to use which option.

Comment: Every query you run, by definition, opens a cursor.  So it is not a question of whether or not to use a cursor.  My guess is that you're talking about the difference between using implicit and explicit cursors which is covered in a few different threads like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010/what-is-the-difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-cursors-in-oracle  If you're asking something else, it would be helpful to include examples of the two different approaches.

Comment: no, i want to understand cursor, if every query opens a cursor and it only deals with select statement, what is need to open a cursor? we can write store procedure without it. Aren't we? It seems like a connection, where we open a cursor and close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many a times we have to perform specific operations based on data from a row or more returned by a result set. To traverse and iterate through each of the row of a result set, we need a handle on the result set.

`CURSOR` allows to define a handle on the result set returned by a `SELECT` statement. Scope of a cursor is for the code block where it is being executed. Unlike a `VIEW`, a `CURSOR` is a *runtime view*, which is not defined and stored as a database object.

When we `OPEN` a cursor, each of the row can be fetched using `FETCH` command and stored into variables. Using the values from those variables you can perform desired business logic and take an action. The next row in the cursor is fetched by iterating the cursor, using a `REPEAT - UNTIL` or any other standard looping practices.

**Conclusion**:
Unless have a handle on each of the row, we can't use values *from each row* for procedural operations.

**Refer to**:

1. [***Cursor (databases)***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29)

   - In SQL procedures, a cursor makes it possible to define a result set
     (a set of data rows) and perform complex logic on a row by row
     basis.
2. [***MySQL: Variables in Stored Programs***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-variables.html)

   - Results from queries can be retrieved into local variables using
     `SELECT ... INTO var_list` or by opening a cursor and using `FETCH
     ... INTO var_list`.
3. [***Oracle: Cursor Variables***](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/cursor_variables.htm)

   - To execute a multi-row query, Oracle opens an unnamed work area that stores 
     processing information. You can access this area through an explicit cursor, 
     which names the work area, or through a cursor variable, 
     which points to the work area..
4. [***SQL Server: Cursors***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191179.aspx)

   - Applications need a mechanism to work with one row or a small block
     of rows at a time. Cursors are an extension to result sets that
     provide that mechanism.

Comment: thank Ravinder, is it possible to use select statement and not to use cursor? then what would be the effect? according to my understanding, once i get the resultset from select query, i can iterate over it and process it. Correct me if I am wrong and if not, please can you sort out my confusion, I am new to it and not able to consume the idea of cursor in my head.

Comment: If a select returns a single row, then no CURSOR is required. You can directly `select .... into var_names ...`.

Comment: and if select returns multiple rows, then can I still use the select statement?

Comment: No. To process multiple rows within a stored procedure, you need a `CURSOR`.