# why we don't need to open and fetch explicit cursor in for loop in pl sql?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I'd like to know why we don't need to open and fetch explicit cursor in for loops in pl sql like this :

```
declare
  REC  EMPLOYEES%ROWTYPE;
  cursor emp_cur is select * from employees; 
begin
  FOR rec in emp_cur loop
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('fname' ||  REC.FIRST_NAME   );
  end loop;
END;
```

Thanks

Comment: Because it is Oracle rules. If you have `FOR` loop for cursor - you don't need to open fetch and close it...

Comment: Actually ORACLE handles OPEN,FETCH,CLOSE internally in case of FOR loops.

Comment: You have to think of the PL/SQL compiler as taking your high-level instructions and generating code for you, in this case including all of the cursor handling. There are a load of other things it does for you implicitly - it's pretty smart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [CURSOR FOR LOOP](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php) does OPEN, FETCH, and CLOSE implicitly. And that is is why these cursors called [implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010/what-is-the-difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-cursors-in-oracle)

> For select_statement, PL/SQL declares, opens, fetches from, and closes an implicit cursor.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155)