# Which are all implicit and explicit cursor here?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Am in soo much of confusion in differentiate between implicit and explicit cursor... please tell me which are all implicit and explicit cursor that am given below. If there are more than this, please also mention that too...

Thanks in advance...!

```
1)SELECT column_nm
   INTO v_a
  FROM table;

2)BEGIN
   FOR i IN cursor_name
   LOOP
    --some logic
   END LOOP;
  END;

3)BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10
   LOOP
    --some logic
   END LOOP;
  END;

4)BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM employees WHERE 1=2)
   LOOP
    --some logic
   END LOOP;
  END;

5)BEGIN
   OPEN cursor_name...
    FETCH...INTO...
     EXIT WHEN...
     --some logic
   CLOSE cursor_name;
  END;
  /
```

Comment: 2+5 are explicit, 1+4 is implicit. what the difference is, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010/what-is-the-difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-cursors-in-Oracle)

Comment: @hotfix why 4th is called as implicit cursor...is there any memory space occupy to store.

Comment: because you do not define a cursor, pl/sql engine do it for you. it also handles alls operation for you like open, close, fetch. and you can't reference it with the name like an explicit cursor

Comment: ok..but when i define a cursor attribute for 4th like SQL%ROWCOUNT it will not work..Now my question is ``'Implicit cursor work with attributes?'``

Answer (score 1):

As @hotfix comment, **explicit** cursor is when you **define cursor name** as `cursor_name` (2 and 5)

3 section is using a simple [counter](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/for_loop.php) and not cursor